# Issue in custom validation message using messages.properties file in spring boot validation

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

**I am using spring validation to validate the Rest Controller input, I would appreciate if any one can tell me is there a possibility of throwing custom message in case of exception and the custom message should come from properties file.**

UserController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping(
        value="/",
        method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public Object[] createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    new UserValidator().validate(user,bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return  bindingResult.getFieldErrors().toArray();
    }
}
```

UserValidator.java

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return User.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "user.firstName.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", "user.lastName.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "slug", "user.slug.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "user.email.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "user.password.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "phone", "user.phone.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "address", "user.address.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "country", "user.country.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "gender", "user.gender.empty");

    User user = (User) obj;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", 
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    if(!errors.hasErrors()) {
        if (!(pattern.matcher(user.getEmail()).matches())) {
            errors.rejectValue("email", "user.email.invalid");
        }
    }
}
}
```

messages.properties

```
# messages.properties
user.firstName.empty=Enter a valid first name.
user.lastName.empty = Enter a valid last name.
user.slug.empty = Select gender.
user.phone.empty = Select gender.
user.address.empty = Select gender.
user.country.empty = Select gender.
user.password.empty = Select gender.
user.gender.empty = Select gender. 
user.email.empty = Enter a valid email.
user.email.invalid = Invalid email! Please enter valid email.
```

CustomMessageSourceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class CustomMessageSourceConfiguration {
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
}
```

Browser Response

```
 {codes: ["user.firstName.empty.user.firstName", "user.firstName.empty.firstName",…], arguments: 
null,…} 
codes: ["user.firstName.empty.user.firstName", "user.firstName.empty.firstName",…]
0: "user.firstName.empty.user.firstName"
1: "user.firstName.empty.firstName"
2: "user.firstName.empty.java.lang.String"
3: "user.firstName.empty"
arguments: null
defaultMessage: null
objectName: "user"
field: "firstName"
rejectedValue: null
bindingFailure: false
code: "user.firstName.empty"
```

Comment: I got the answer, We can add 4th Parameter to 

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", 
    "user.firstName.empty","Field cannot be empty");

in UserValidator.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way to Validate**

**We can create seperate bean validation.**

**Users.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

   @NotNull
   @InBetweenNumberCustom(min = 12,max = 18)
   private Integer age;

   //getters and setters 
}
```

**Here we are going to create @InBetweenNumberCustom validation annotation.**

```
import com.something.validator.ConstraintValidator.InBetweenNumberValidator;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, 
ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(InBetweenNumberCustom.List.class)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {InBetweenNumberValidator.class})
public @interface InBetweenNumberCustom {

String message() default "Must be in between {min} and {max}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

int min() default 0;

int max() default 2147483647;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, 
ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented

public @interface List {
    InBetweenNumberCustom[] value();
}
}
```

**InBetweenNumberValidator.java**

```
import com.something.validator.annonations.InBetweenNumberCustom;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class InBetweenNumberValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<InBetweenNumberCustom,Integer> {
private int minValue;
private int maxValue;

@Override
public void initialize(InBetweenNumberCustom inBetweenNumberCustom) {
    this.minValue = inBetweenNumberCustom.min();
    this.maxValue = inBetweenNumberCustom.max();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Integer aInteger, ConstraintValidatorContext 
constraintValidatorContext) {
    // null values are not valid
    if ( aInteger == null ) return false;
    else return aInteger <= this.maxValue && aInteger >= this.minValue;
}
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
public JSONObject createUser(@Validated @RequestBody User user, 
BindingResult bindingResult) {
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another Way Of Validation**

We can autowire MessageSource to UserController.java which is configured in CustomMessageSourceConfiguration.java to get messages.properties file.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

public  User  createUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") @RequestBody User 
user) {
   final ArrayList errorList = new ArrayList<>() {};
    bindingResult.getFieldErrors().forEach(fieldError -> {
        errorList.add(new 
  ObjectError(fieldError.getField(),messageSource.getMessage(fieldError.getCode(), 
  null, Locale.getDefault())));
    });
```

Now we get required error message mapping from messages.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

**Another Way Of Validation**

We can add 4th Parameter As Error Message without using messages.properties file.

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
return User.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", 
"user.firstName.empty","Error Message Here");
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", 
"user.lastName.empty","Error Message Here");
...
... 
}
}
```